# Error code when trying to install krpc python module using pip

Tags: python, installation, pip

Whenever I try to install krpc module for python I keep getting this error.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQNpX.png)

Code: `pip install krpc`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! Copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.